# Cannot kill process with powershell (Stop-Process)

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, ps

I have a ps1 script (Windows 2008 R2) to kill process:

```
 Stop-Process -Name "c_proc".
```

c_proc is a program that runs in console mode.
After running this script `c_proc` does not exit, it just keeps restarting in console mode.
Another way to kill `c_proc` is to kill conhost.exe but it didn't work either.
`c_proc` can exit when you type in its console windows "exit".
How can I send the message "exit" to the console window via PowerShell or cmd?
How can I kill `c_proc`?

Comment: How do you start `c_proc`? Add some code to the question, so it can be analyzed.

Comment: It sounds like c_proc is a child process. What happens if you kill its parent process?

Comment: Thanks for idea. I found parent process "start.exe". And edit the script. Now it kill all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the right code to kill the process `c_proc`. I found the parent process:

```
  Stop-Process -Name "start"
  Stop-Process -Name "c_proc"
```